# What is the order of evaluation in a PLINQ query?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, plinq

Below is a sample PLINQ query I'm running periodically in a Windows service:

```
var resultList = new List<Task<SendMailResult>>();

try
{
    resultList = emailsToSend
        .AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(10)
        .Select(async e =>
        {
            bool bSuccess = false;

            if (await MailHelper.SendMailAsync(e.sTo, e.sSubject, e.sHTML) == true)
            {
                bSuccess = true;
            }

            return new SendMailResult
            {
                succeeded = bSuccess,
                resultid = e.id
            };
        }).ToList();

    Task.WaitAll(resultList.ToArray());
}
catch (AggregateException aggEx)
{
    foreach (var ex in aggEx.InnerExceptions)
        Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

My question is - if an exception were to be thrown in the inner anonymous  `async Func<EmailToSend, Task<SendMailResult>>` (while calling MailHelper.SendMailAsync(), most likely), and thus then the AggregateException handler will be invoked - will the following `.ToList()` have been invoked at any point?

In other words, is it possible that some of the tasks completed successfully until one did not, and following the code snippet below after being caught in the AggregateException handler, I may have a resultList with a non-0 Count? Or will an exception mean that the ToList() is never invoked, and resultList will always be empty if an exception is thrown?

I realise I am swimming with sharks using this kind of multithreaded power without a full understanding of its implications. Hence the question! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ToList()` will be invoked at any point because of `Select` [laziness](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2007/06/02/lazy-evaluation-in-c.aspx) and result list will contain all tasks.
Execution will begin with `.ToList()` method call. `Select` will only provide `IEnumerable` which can be enumerated to list.
If some tasks will fail with exception you will catch them and after all you will get the list of tasks, where some tasks will have `Faulted` status.

**Edit:**
Exception throwing will be triggered by `Task.WaitAll` method call, so list will be created before and will have exact items count as initial collection.

**Update:**
About `Task.WaitAll` inner structure:
If you want to know how it works, you may look at [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,72b6b3fa5eb35695).
At first it [collects all incompleted tasks](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5056) and then [waits](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5094) for these tasks to complete.
After then it [collects all inner exceptions](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5141) from all tasks and then raises it as single `AggregateException`.

Comment: Interesting! So it is *guaranteed*, after executing the code above, that resultList will be a List of Tasks, equal in Count to the emailsToSend IEnumerable?

Comment: Yes. Because exception will be thrown only on `Task.WaitAll` call. It will be called after list creation, so list will have expected length.

Comment: So therefore, any further processing should check for something like:
`resultList.Where(t=>t.IsFaulted==false).Select(t=>t.Result).Where(...`, right?

Comment: If you don't care about failed results then yes.

Comment: Marvellous, thanks. If this question doesn't get any more insightful answers within 24 hours, yours will be the accepted answer.

Comment: Last clarification. If the AggregateException is raised, and execution of its handler begins, at that point are all tasks guaranteed to have finished?

In other words, if an exception is raised in one of the Tasks, is the AggregateException raised at that point, or is it only raised once Task.WaitAll() completes?

(Hopefully as I understand it, Tas.WaitAll() must complete, and the AggregateException is then raised, containing all the InnerExceptions from faulted tasks.)